# question about mysqli prepare

Tags: php, mysqli

I have following mysqli configuration settings on a separate file:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
```

Now, I have some functions in a class which is on another file.
Sth like:

```
function username_exists($username){
    global $mysqli;
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=?")) {
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $count=$stmt->num_rows;
        $stmt->close();
    }
    return ($count > 0 ? true : false);
    }
```

I was wondering about:

1. Why do i need to include `global $mysqli`; inside each function in the class, if i dont include, i get error message like:

   Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in...
2. What does `$stmt->store_result();` do? If I do not include it, it returns 0 rows.
3. Do I need to use `$stmt->close();`  after each query? (For example I have other functions below that function, do I need to use it at the end of each function or end of last function in the class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First question:** If your object reference `$mysqli` is defined outside the function, it must be either passed in as a parameter to the function like `function username_exists($username, $mysqli)` or referenced with the `global` keyword.  The function parameter method is probably preferable, to avoid using global scope variables in context of function scope.  If you don't do either of these, `$mysqli` is not known inside the function since the function cannot see outside its own scope.

If you want to avoid referencing the global `$mysqli`, I would suggest including a MySQLi object as a member of your class.  After you pass in an existing MySQLi object, you can reference it in each function as `$this->mysqli`

```
class My_Class()
{
  public $mysqli;
  // everything else

  function some_func()
  {
    $this->mysqli->prepare();
    // etc
  }
}
$x = new My_Class();
$x->mysqli = $mysqli; // or new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
```

**Second question:** `$stmt->store_result()` retrieves the full result set from the completed query called by `execute()`.  Without it, MySQLi has not yet requested any results to be returned from the MySQL server, even though the query may have been successful.  It is necessary only for a `SELECT` query that returns rows.

**Third question:** If you are calling the same SQL statement over and over in a loop, you don't need to call `$stmt->close()` after each iteration.  It is a good idea to call `$stmt->close()` in other circumstances, freeing memory and letting the MySQL server know you are done using that statement and result set.

Comment: Thanks for detailed reply. Is it okay to use `global $mysqli;` inside each function, like im already doing?