# PHP PDO not deleting 2 fields from user table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to delete a username and password from a table using PDO. Below is the code that I'm using. It inserts fine, does everything else perfect. It's a script I've got from the internet. The most decent one I could find. But I'm very new to PHP PDO and need some help deleting a username and password from a table.

```
<?php

function dbconnect()
{
global $pdo;

try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=redgrace_staxapp', 'root', '');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('MySQL connection fail! ' . $e->getMessage());
}
}

function insert_new_user($username, $password)
{
# checking username is already taken
if (username_exists($username))
return FALSE;

# insert new user info
global $pdo;
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('
     INSERT INTO users
    (username, password)
    values (:username, :password)');

$stmt->execute( array(':username' => $username, ':password' => md5($password)) );

if ($pdo->lastInsertId())
     return true;
else
    return false;
}

function delete_user($username, $password)
{

if (username_exists($username))
     return FALSE;


global $pdo;
$stmt   = "DELETE FROM users WHERE username = :username and password = :password";


$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();



   }

   function username_exists($username)
   {

global $pdo;

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('
    SELECT id
    FROM users
     WHERE username = :username
    LIMIT 1');

$stmt->execute( array('username' => $username) );
return $stmt->fetchColumn();
}

function attempt($username, $password)
{
global $pdo;

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('
    SELECT id, username
    FROM users
    WHERE username = :username AND password = :password
    LIMIT 1');

$stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username, 'password' => md5($password)));

if ($data = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_OBJ )) {
    # set session
    $_SESSION['username'] = $data->username;
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}

function is_user()
{
if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
    return true;
}

function redirect($url)
{
header('Location: ' .$url);
exit;
}

function valid_username($str){
return preg_match('/^[a-z0-9_-]{3,16}$/', $str);
}

function valid_password($str){
return preg_match('/^[a-z0-9_-]{6,18}$/', $str);
}
?>
```

Would be great if anyone can help me.

Comment: How are you accessing `username_exists` function?

Comment: Without a `$` it's a function. @Jessica with `$` it's a variable. Not a working one, but a function nonetheless. The syntax of it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- if you do `$username_exists()` which is what was originally in your comment, you are calling a function. It just doesn't make any sense because `$username_exists` never got passed into `delete_user` - which would make it undefined. A function just called `username_exists` would still be visible at that point.

Comment: And why are you using `global $pdo;` twice? Plus, you shouldn't be using `global`, you should be passing `$pdo` as a parameter.

Comment: @Jessica It was merely an example to show the OP that the way he/she is doing it now, will fail. If you want to fix it the way it should be, then be my guest. The OP will be back, I guarantee it. The OP is nowhere to be found at the moment, so how it's used, is anybody's guess.

Comment: Here's an example on how someone else is using it as a "function" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212180/question-about-mysqli-prepare @Jessica and you should be passing your question/comment to the OP, not me. ;-)

Comment: This `$stmt = "DELETE...` should most likely be `$stmt = $pdo->prepare("DELETE...` then get rid of `$stmt   = $pdo->prepare($sql);` plus you're never calling your `delete_user()` function.

Comment: And do read the manual http://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Comment: @Fred-ii- YOU WROTE $username_exists($user); I don't see any edits on the OP. I was talking to you, and you deleted the post I was replying to, so I deleted mine. It is a fact that `$username_exists()` will attempt to call a function. The OP is not currently doing that, and you make no sense.

Comment: I didn't delete anything. @Jessica you did actually, in response to my first initial comment to the OP.

Comment: Which you deleted where it had a bunch of comments about calling `$username_exists($username)`. Whatever, lie if you want to, I'm done.

Comment: Oh, and "I" make no sense? The OP's "code" makes no sense. And I don't know why you're throwing all this at me, anyway. Plus I knew none of the answers would work, said he'd be back, and will. @Jessica I'm done here.

Comment: The only part of OP's code that is wrong is the second to last line. Every other part is perfectly valid and makes plenty of sense to me.

Comment: So, the problem has been solved then. Ask the OP to accept your answer then. @Jessica

Comment: @ everyone. Just updated the code above. Sorry for the confusion by not adding enough code. My mistake. Please let me know if this will help. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

```
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
```

Do them one at a time (or use an array and execute)

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

```
$stmt->execute(['username'=>$username, 'password'=>$password]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, ':password', $password);
```

to:

```
$sth->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

I have tried again to edit your code, you don't need to use global variable, because you instantiate the PDO class directly and use it on the fly.

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=redgrace_staxapp', 'root', '');
        $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die('MySQL connection fail! ' . $e->getMessage());
    }



    function delete_user($username, $password)
    {

        if (username_exists($username))
            return TRUE;


     $query  = "DELETE FROM users WHERE username = :username and password = :password";
     $stmt   = $pdo->prepare($query);
     $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->execute();

    }
```

Comment: Hi Mubo. I tried your suggestion, but i still seem to be stuck. not deleting it...

Comment: where have you defined the variable $sql. What does this variables holds.

Comment: This (in your code) `$stmt   = "DELETE...` should most likely be `$stmt = $pdo->prepare("DELETE...` then get rid of `$stmt   = $pdo->prepare($sql);` @user3143499 as stated in my comments underneath your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find error if any like this (DETAILS: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php ):

```
global $pdo;
$sql   = "DELETE FROM users WHERE username = :username and password = :password";
$stmt   = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
  if (!$stmt) {
        print_r($pdo->errorInfo());
    }
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: @user3143499 : did you try it?